# How do I download all the versions of a file with 100,000+ versions from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning, versions

I'm using the AWS command line on Windows and all methods I have found till now seem to suggest I need to get a list of version-ids for all the objects. Is there some sort of wildcard like * that I can use?

Comment: Maybe use http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-manage-amazon-s3-versioning-with-cloudberry-explorer/?

Comment: Is this a one-off requirement (in which jamod's suggestion of using a tool like Cloudberry Explorer is better), or will it be a repeating need (requiring scripting/programming)? What will you be doing with 100,000+ versions of a file? Any extra info you can provide would assist us in providing a useful answer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am running dark matter simulations, each time-step corresponds to a new version of the file. A one-time download is what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Python code using `boto` will download all versions of files found in a bucket. It's possible that a large number of versions will require paging through the result set.

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('BUCKET')

# Get a list of all versions contained in the bucket
versions = bucket.list_versions(prefix='FILENAME')

for v in versions:
  # Save the version to a filename based on the Last Modified date
  v.get_contents_to_filename(v.last_modified)
```

Answer (score 4):

With **Boto3** the solution from John needs to be updated as below. I am saving the files with the modified ts.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

_bucket = '<s3Bucket>'
_file   = '<fileName>'
_key    = '<the s3 prefix>' + _file
_local  = '<local path>' + _file

response = client.list_object_versions(
    Bucket=_bucket,
    Prefix=_key
)

for v in response['Versions']:
    client.download_file(_bucket, _key,
                         _local + '_' + v['LastModified'].strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'),
                         ExtraArgs={"VersionId": v["VersionId"]})
    print(v['LastModified'])
```